# DSC Power 832 - Security Setup Takeover

Tags: home-automation, security, alarm

I have a [DSC 832 control panel](https://www.dsc.com/alarm-security-products/Power832%20-%20Power832/896) that I see installed in a house I moved to recently.

However, I am not sure where to begin to take control of the system. Could someone point me to a starting point?

**Questions**;

1. How do I check what devices are currently connected and monitored by the system?
2. How do I get alarm notifications on my mobile device?

**EDIT**
I could trace at least three of them going to a - DVR system, motion sensor, and smoke alarm in the basement. I also see a large number of wires into the control panel. Is there usually a user interface to control such systems?

Attached how the control panel looks from inside[image: Inside View of DSC Control Panel]

Comment: It may be helpful if you can provide a link to the product that you are asking about

Comment: Typically these are installed and serviced by a "security company". Something like (not a recommendation, just an example), ADT. See if there are any labels anywhere, possibly with a service/support #. Check with previous owner, if you can.

Comment: I don't see any label on the following - a DVR system, a control panel, two keypads. I believe they may have been managing it as a DIY. I don't mind managing it myself. I just need to know where to start. Though I have written to the realtor of the previous owner and I am hoping I get a reply.

Comment: Do you see any security devices like window or door opening detectors or cameras. Or any wires sticking out of a wall where items like that may have been previously?

Comment: All windows and doors beep when opened, and there are multiple cameras outside. I don't see any wires at all around these devices. I do see a lot of wires in the control panel that is in the basement.

Comment: This should have been addressed as a condition of sale at the time of sale, but too late for that. If you don't get cooperation from the previous owner you may need to replace the central panel (you may well be able to continue to use the sensors and cameras already in place, but figuring out what is what will be up to you.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Agreed on the condition of the sale. Most people don't think of these things at all, and despite being a technologist I did not pay importance to the same until now.

Comment: Searching on **Anatel PC1832** brings up a bunch of info you might want to look into.

Comment: I have tried searching and have the installation and user manuals downloaded, but one part that I am unsure of is - how do I check what devices are attached to the control panel and what is the status of each?